# ¿Como comparo dos valores de un input type="password"?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario en el que un usuario se daría de alta. Necesito saber la contraseña que el escribe para compararla con la que vuelve a poner para ver que no se haya equivocado.

El código sería este:

```js
 <script>
  function balidatu(){
   var pas1 = $("#pass").val();
            var pas2 = $("#passC").val();
            return();
        }
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="tipo_contenido" content="text/html;" http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8">
 <title>Quizzes</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesPWS/style.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' 
     type='text/css' 
     media='only screen and (min-width: 530px) and (min-device-width: 481px)'
     href='stylesPWS/wide.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' 
     type='text/css' 
     media='only screen and (max-width: 480px)'
     href='stylesPWS/smartphone.css' />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id='page-wrap'>
 <header class='main' id='h1'>
      <span class="right"><a href='logIn.html'>LogIn</a> </span>
 <h2>Quiz: crazy questions</h2>
    </header>
 <nav class='main' id='n1' role='navigation'>
  <span><a href='layout.html'>Home</a></span>
  <span><a href='quizzes.html'>Quizzes</a></span>
  <span><a href='credits.html'>Credits</a></span>
 </nav>
    <section class="main" id="s1">
    
 <div>
   <form id="galderenF" name="galderenF" method="post" action="signUp.php" onsubmit="return balidatu()">
    
    <label for="posta"><strong>Posta (*):</strong></label>
    <input type="email" name="posta" id="posta" placeholder="Zein da zure posta?"  pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,}[0-9]{3}@ikasle\.ehu\.(eus|es)"  required/><br>
    
    <label for="deitura"><strong>Deitura (*):</strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="deitura" minlength="10" id="galdera" placeholder="Zein da zure galdera?" required/><br>
    
    <label for="nick"><strong>Nick (*):</strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="nick" id="erantzunZuzena" placeholder="Zein da zure erantzun zuzena?" required/><br>
    
    <label for="pasahitza" id="pass"><strong>Pasahitza (*):</strong></label>
    <input type="password" name="pasahitza" minlength = "6" id="erantzunOkerra" placeholder="Erantzun okerra 1" required/><br>
    
    <label for="pasEr" id="passC"><strong>Pasahitza Errepikatu (*):</strong></label>
    <input type="password" name="pasahitzaRep" minlength = "6" id="erantzunOkerra" placeholder="Erantzun okerra 2" required/><br>
    
    <input class="botoia" type="submit" id="botoia1" value="Bidali" />
    <input class="botoia" type="reset" id="botoia2" value="Reset" />
    <div id="aster" ><strong> * | Nahitaezko hutsuneak </strong></div><br><br>
    
    
   </form>
    </section>
 <footer class='main' id='f1'>
  <p><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiz" target="_blank">What is a Quiz?</a></p>
  <a href='https://github.com'>Link GITHUB</a>
 </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema es que al cogerlo como lo estoy cogiendo me pone como si el campo estuviera vacío. Es como si el valor fuera un String vacío (algo así: "").

PD: faltan las hojas de estilo pero no es algo importante para mí duda.

Edito para decir que se me ha olvidado comentar que he probado con esto y no funciona:

```
var pas1 = $("#pass").val().replace(/./g,'*');
```

Saludos.

Comment: Los id a los que hay que hacer objetivo son `erantzunOkerra y erantzunOkerra` respectivamente, `pass y passC` son solo labels

Comment: Vale, ya he visto el fallo. Menuda tontería, gracias por responder.

Comment: He arreglado el fallo de los id-s cambiandolos por pass y passC y sigue sin funcionar. Coge las contraseñas como si fueran asteriscos por lo que con comparar dos contraseñas de la misma longitud lo da por valido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con comparar los valores de los dos campos tienes. Yo he probado y val() te devuelve la clave introducida en el campo de tipo password. Así pues tu funcion de validar deberia quedar así

```
<script>
    function balidatu(){
        var pas1 = $("#pass").val();
        var pas2 = $("#passC").val();
        return (pas1 === pas2);
    }
</script>
```

De manera tal que devuelve true si son iguales y falso si son diferentes, así puedes usarla en el evento onSubmit del formulario y enviar o no los datos basados en si esta correctamente validado este aspecto de tu formulario.

Comment: Ahora funciona perfecto. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar puedes usar una condición en JavaScript.
Ej:

```
function validarContraseña(){
    if($("#pass").val() === $("#passC").val()){
         //Si son iguales
         console.log("Las contraseñas son iguales");
    }else if($("#pass").val() !== $("#passC").val()){
         //Si no son iguales
         console.log("Las contraseñas no son iguales");
    }
}
```

Comment: El `else-if` sobraría ya que, si no se cumple el `if` entonces para este caso no habrá necesidad de validar nuevamente si las contraseñas son o no iguales.